command/macro/... to exit-recursive-edit then immediately reenter?
BRIEF: In frequently do abort or exit recursive-edit followed immediately by a new recursive edit. Two key bindings, several kerystrokes.
Q: is there a way to make this into a command or macro that can be invoked by a single emacs key binding?
DETAIL:
I frequently exit-recursive-edit or abort-recursive-edit,  and then immediately reenter with recursive-edit.
In keyboard bindings
M-x exit recursive-edit RET
M-x recursive-edit RET

or
M-x abort-recursive-edit RET
M-x recursive-edit RET

I think that's C-M-C C-r or `C-r C-] in the standard keyboard bindings.
Actually, I usually (but not always) use the following instead of recursive-edit
(defun recursive-edit-saving-window-setup ()
  "Recursive edit saving window setup and position in buffer"
  (interactive)
  (let ((savpos (point-marker)))
    (save-window-excursion
      (recursive-edit))
      (goto-char savpos)))

so that when I enter a recursive-edit I can freely change windows, and then pop back out to the same window configuration, as well as resuming or aborting what was happening when I started the recursive edit.
I would like to have a single key sequence to do this.
However, the naive
(defun exit-recursive-edit-and-reenter () 
     (interactive)
     (exit-recursive-edit)
     (recursive-edit))

does not work, because exit-recursive-edit behaves as if it was throwing to where the recursive-edit was called.
Similarly emacs keyboard macros.
(Keyboard macros outside of emacs work, e.g. AutoHotKey, but I would prefer an emacs solution.)

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Sorry about that.  BTW, there are an unfortunately large number of Q&As  on  emacs.se  that are NOT about elisp programming,  where the question and often the answer is about what magic key combinations do X.  Is there any way to  search that excludes that sort of stuff?

Search for your X. Maybe search for tags with names that include key. Maybe search for tag [commands]. Sounds like you're looking for a command or its key sequence. Describe what you want to do in your question, and ask if there's a command/key to do it.

Trying not to be sarcastic... "Sounds like you're looking for a command or its key sequence" is exactly what I was NOT searching for, since I already did what you suggested (which is always the first thing anyone does, in emacs docs, web, SE, and now in LLMs) and was relatively sure it did not exist.  I was asking for the best way to write elisp to do something like defadvice after recursive-edit returns, to check a flag set by some flavor of exit-recursive-edit.  But such a defadvice doesn't work for wrappers such as recursive-edit-saving-window-setup.  I.e. seeking elisp code.

Anyway: I made my wrapper recursive-edit-saving-window-setup loop when a global flag set by new wrapperexit-recursive-edit-then-reenter is not set, etc.  // Better than nothing, but suboptimal in using a global flag, gets confused if traditional recursive-edit has been used (that I might to defadvice to clear the flag), change has to be made to any such wrappers, etc.  // It would have been nice(r?) if the equivalent of the two back to back commands could have been done - but that doesn't work AFAICT because the two commands are executed by two different command loops.

And in case you want something relevant to language concepts - in Perl I think I might have been able to use RAII to avoid some of the shortcomings the the global flag approach.
